# How to convert Int to constant for res/raw?

Tags: java, android

```
 InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ac);
```

here, ac is constant file name from res/raw.

```
int books = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DictionaryDatabase.BOOK_DETAILS)
```

is an int contains name: ac also.

Is it possible to use

`InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource`(**Int books**);
???

If yes how??

Comment: cursor is usually a matter of some SQL database. What you are trying to do is maybe to read books from the DB but its the wrong way. DB is not a "constant file name from res/raw". Also DB's table names and its fields names are usually a public static Strings in corresponding class definition. Thas why DictionaryDatabase.BOOK_DETAILS works it is only a name of a column

Comment: @Stan: you'r right. here int books is a cursor to get name of file from SQL using search. when user search for Apple this cursor will return ac that is exact same name saved on res/raw. I was thinking if there is any way to use that int to open file from res/raw

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to get the value of the `R.raw.xxxx` field having the name `xxxx` in a variable. This can be achieved with a code like this:

```
String resName = "mybook";
int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "raw", context.getPackageName());
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(resId);
```

Here, `context` is an instance of `Context` in your app, in an activity, this would be `this`.

Comment: @ Aleks G: Actually no. i want to get resId from cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DictionaryDatabase.BOOK_DETAILS) not fromcontext.getResources().getIdentifier

Comment: @netmaster Then I don't understand what the problem is.  The only thing to keep in mind here is that the actual values in `R.raw` are defined during the build process (and may changed on a rebuild), therefore you cannot rely on them until the app is running.  Hence in your database helper class constructor or `onCreate` (and `onUpgrade`) you'll need to save these values into the database.  At the same time, you could save yourself a lot of pain by simply saving the names of the resources and obtaining the ID at runtime, as I showed.

Comment: @ Aleks G: Actually int books is a cursor to get name of file from SQL using search. when user search for Apple this cursor will return ac that is exact same name saved on res/raw. I was thinking if there is any way to use that int to open file from res/raw. but seems its not possible by this way, am I right?

Comment: @netmaster You'are right. While not impossible, it's too much hustle (in my opinion) to do it this way.  You can continue with the same logic, just store the name of the resource, not it's integer ID, into the database - and then open it by name.